# Proof of dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I was going through the proof of the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Now if we have that  ($f$$_n$) is a sequence of measurable functions such that $\lvert f_n\rvert$ $\le$ $g$ for all n where g is integrable on $\Bbb{R}$.
And if $f$ = $\lim_{n}$$f_n$ almost everwhere.

We can show that ($g+f_n$) is a sequence of non-negative measurable functions.

Then by Fatou's lemma, we have that $\int$liminf($g+f_n$)$d$$x$ $\le$ liminf$\int$($g+f_n$)$d$$x$.

Now from here, we can obtain that

$\int$($g+f$)$d$$x$ $\le$ $\int$$gdx$+liminf $\int$$f_ndx$.How?

Please explain this last step.I know that since both are integrable, the integral can be seperated..but how is liminf seperated in the right-hand side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the liminf, $\int g$ is just a number. So what it says is that
$$
\liminf_n(c+f_n)=c+\liminf _nf_n,
$$
where $c=\int g$.

Comment: So..is that always true? ..liminf(c+an) = c+liminfan?

Comment: Yes. How could translating a set by a fixed distance could change it in any other way? If you move a set 10 units to the right, the infimum will increase by 10.

Comment: Are you sure $\int$g is a number?

Comment: for example..what if g(x)=x?

Comment: I can see it is independent of n..it's a constant sequence

Comment: In the setup of your question, where the space is $\mathbb R$ and I assume Lebesgue measure, $g(x)=x$ is not integrable. In any case, Lebesgue integration and its theorem are about integrals, not antiderivatives.